# Slow navigation using react router dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to link the login page to dashboard and then dashboard to a details page and there will also be a logout that takes me to the login page again. But the navigation is sooo slow. Is there any problem in the way i defined my routes?

```
       <Routes>
          <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
            <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route
              path="/dashboard/:measurementId"
              element={<MeasurementDetails />}
            />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
```

This is the private route component

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const hasToken = LocalStorageService.getElement('token')
    return (
      <> 
        {hasToken ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to='/login'/>}
      </>
  )
}

export default PrivateRoutes
```

I used the path in login like this

```
onSubmit: async (data) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        await auth.login(data);
        navigate("/dashboard");
      }
```

And dashboard is basically just a list of item rows and each is selectable and takes you to details page

```
 onRowSelect={(rowData) =>
            !isLoading && navigate(`/dashboard/${rowData.data.id}`)
          }
```

And then the button to leave details page

```
<Button
          onClick={() => navigate(`/dashboard`)}
          label="Indietro " />
```

Comment: what do you mean by slow ?

Comment: i mean, when i click the login button, it takes like 15 seconds before it goes to the dashboard. When i click logout, it takes again 15 ore more. I wonder if its a problem withthe react router don maybe the way i did the paths is wrong.

Comment: what version of react router are you using ?

Comment: I am using version 6.4.3

Comment: <Routes>
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
            <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route
              path="dashboard/:measurementId"
              element={<MeasurementDetails />}
            />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>

Comment: Try the above comment

Comment: Thank you, now when I go from login to dashboard it loads fast, Logout and dashboard to details is still slow. :/ And doesnt show the data of :measurementId anymore in details page

Comment: <Routes> <Route path="/dashboard" element={<PrivateRoutes />}> <Route index element={<Dashboard />} /> <Route path=":measurementId" element={<MeasurementDetails />} /> </Route> <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} /> </Routes>

Comment: try the above code

Comment: the login is perfect, the other routes are slow and something interesting happens because it does change the link and if i refresh it directs me to the page immediately. if i dont refresh it is stuck for seconds.

Comment: can you add your private routes component and your dashboard component to the question ? thanks

Comment: I just did, added some other info you might find helpful too

Comment: This might be a bit unrelated, but I would suggest that you use code splitting with `React.lazy()` to improve the performance. This might || might not improve the page navigation speed, but will improve the perf for sure.
So instead of `import Login from './pages/Login.js` do something like `const Login = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/Login.js'))`

Comment: @Dev-Siri thanks, will surely try to improve my code with that! I appreciate it!

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by "slow". Is this a complete [mcve]? I don't see any issue with any of the routing/navigation components you are using. Is *your* code doing any sort of asynchronous check prior to navigating, like an auth/token/etc check for each route transition?

Comment: It is fixed now. I tried the solution from @unhackit and it works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer came from on of the commenters, @unhackit and it went as follows

```
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
          <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path=":measurementId" element={<MeasurementDetails />} />
       </Route>
     </Routes>
```